# Sum over different distributions

Tags: statistics, approximation

Let me say that I have a sum of N random variables that follow a specific distribution. Let's say Nakagami-m. The sum can be approximated by the normal.

The problem is that, given four different probabilities, the m changes. More specifically, with P1  I sum all the N variables but all of them are following Nakagami-1, with P2 all follow Nakagami-2 etc.

If the case was just a sum of N iid random variables following a specific Nakagami-m I would approximate them by the normal.
Now what do I do? It seems like X = P1*Sum(Nakagami-1) + ... + P4*Sum(Nakagami-4) where each sum sums N iid variables.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a mixture distribution

Comment: Thanks for the identification. At least I can google rn :)